# Django - Overriding the Model.create() method?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

The [Django docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods) only list examples for overriding `save()` and `delete()`. However, I'd like to define some extra processing for my models **only when they are created**. For anyone familiar with Rails, it would be the equivalent to creating a `:before_create` filter. Is this possible?

Answer (score 209, accepted):

Overriding `__init__()` would cause code to be executed whenever the python representation of object is instantiated. I don't know rails, but a `:before_created` filter sounds to me like it's code to be executed when the object is created in the database. If you want to execute code when a new object is created in the database, you should override `save()`, checking if the object has a `pk` attribute or not. The code would look something like this:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.pk:
        # This code only happens if the objects is
        # not in the database yet. Otherwise it would
        # have pk
    super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I've actually found a solution using signals: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/ (the pre_save signal, specifically). However, this seems to be a much more pragmatic solution. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: nice hack. I'd still prefer to override the create method as I'd like to add a logging.info call after creation of a new object. Calling it before and you have chance of that the the call to the parent method fail...

Comment: I assume you mean overriding the manager method `create`? That's an interesting solution, but it wouldn't work in cases when the object is being created using `Object(**kwargs).save()` or any other variation on that.

Comment: I don't think it's a hack. It's one of the official solutions.

Comment: You can override the create method with a custom manager or add a classmethod on the model class. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/instances/#creating-objects

Comment: Shouldn't it be `super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)` ?

Comment: @ground5hark you can have it both *a method* **and** *using signals*, I posted below the "have the cake and eat it too" solution because this is the first thing people see when googling how to do this :) cheers!

Comment: Maybe checking for `self.pk` is not the best option to check if the object is newly being created or just updating. Sometimes you provide object id in creation time (a customized non-database generated value like `KSUID`), and it'll cause this clause never to execute... 

There is `self._state.adding` value to make sure if it's saving for the first time or just updating, which helps in those cases.

Comment: Thanks, Its a great solution with a single if condition... Good one@Zach.

Answer (score 45):

To answer the question literally, the `create` method in a model's manager is a standard way to create new objects in Django.  To override, do something like

```
from django.db import models

class MyModelManager(models.Manager):
    def create(self, **obj_data):
        # Do some extra stuff here on the submitted data before saving...
        # For example...
        obj_data['my_field'] = my_computed_value(obj_data['my_other_field'])

        # Now call the super method which does the actual creation
        return super().create(**obj_data) # Python 3 syntax!!

class MyModel(models.model):
    # An example model
    my_field = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    my_other_field = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    objects = MyModelManager()
```

In this example, I'm overriding the Manager's method `create` method to do some extra processing before the instance is actually created.

**NOTE:** Code like

`my_new_instance = MyModel.objects.create(my_field='my_field value')`

will execute this modified `create` method, but code like

`my_new_unsaved_instance = MyModel(my_field='my_field value')`

will not.

Comment: I believe you have to call `super(MyModelManager, self).create(**obj_data)` instead of only `super().create(**obj_data)`.  Other than that, this is a brilliant solution

Comment: Like the comment says, Python 3 syntax!!

Comment: I think this is the best solution after the "save" overload. The logic of signals is harder to follow, and does not fit the neat class-based solution of Django models. I always prefer overloading model methods or using Managers, instead of signals.

Answer (score 43):

This is old, has an accepted answer that works (Zach's), and a more idiomatic one too (Michael Bylstra's), but since it's still the first result on Google most people see, **I think we need a more best-practices modern-django style answer here**:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

class MyModel(models.Model):
    # ...
    @classmethod
    def post_create(cls, sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
        if not created:
            return
        # ...what needs to happen on create

post_save.connect(MyModel.post_create, sender=MyModel)
```

The point is this:

1. use signals (read more [here in the official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/signals/#post-save))
2. use a method for nice namespacing (if it makes sense) ...and I marked it as `@classmethod` instead of `@staticmethod` because most likely you'll end up needing to refer static class members in the code

Even cleaner would be if core Django would have an actual `post_create` signal. (Imho if you need to pass a boolean arg to change behavior of a method, that should be 2 methods.)

Comment: Woudn't `post_init` be more appropriate? I'm new to signals, but I'd think that the way you set it up, the method is called on every `save()`, so updates would call this, too.

Comment: Even though this is clean and I like it, please note that in Django docs it's stated: "it’s recommended to avoid the application’s root module and its models module to minimize side-effects of importing code". This can basically easily generate circular imports (it did in my case).

Comment: @KurtBourbaki thanks for noticing that. please suggest a better place to put such code, preferably the simplest such place

Comment: @NeuronQ I defined `post_create()` as a function inside the `signals.py` module, as recommended by Django docs. This allowed me to avoid circular imports. Unfortunately, the signal is not in the `MyModel` class, which is a pity.

Answer (score 28):

an example of how to create a post_save signal (from http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/500/)

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    """Create a matching profile whenever a user object is created."""
    if created: 
        profile, new = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)
```

here is a thoughtful discussion on whether it's best to use signals or custom save methods https://web.archive.org/web/20120815022107/http://www.martin-geber.com/thought/2007/10/29/django-signals-vs-custom-save-method/

In my opinion using signals for this task is more robust, easier to read but lengthier.

Comment: This is the preferred way instead of messing with object internals, however, if you make modifications to the model in question, and not just creating another in the above example, **don't forget to call `instance.save()`**.  So in this case, there is also a performance penalty since there will be one INSERT and one UPDATE query to the database.

Comment: The link to the signals vs. custom save methods is broken.

Answer (score 7):

Overriding `__init__()` will allow you to execute code when the model is instantiated. Don't forget to call the parent's `__init__()`.

Comment: Ah yes this was the answer. Don't know how I overlooked this. Thanks Ignacio.

Answer (score 3):

You can override the create method with a custom manager or add a classmethod on the model class. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/instances/#creating-objects

Answer (score 1):

The preferred answer is correct but the test to tell whether the object is being created doesn't work if your model derives from UUIDModel. The pk field will already have a value.

In this case, you can do this:

`already_created = MyModel.objects.filter(pk=self.pk).exists()`