# using an attribute from a foreignkey in an auotslugfield populatefrom() in django

Tags: django

I am trying to do this

```
    nvc = models.ForeignKey(Nvc)
    slug = AutoSlugField(max_length=50, unique=True, populate_from=('channel_index','nvc__mac_address'))
    channel_index = models.IntegerField()    
    ...
```

where nvc is a foreignkey with an field mac_address and channel index is a local field

My attempt is based on what is shown to work with "unique_with" in the AutoSlugField ([autoslugfield](http://pydoc.net/django-autoslug/1.3.9/autoslug.fields))

```
# minimum date granularity is shifted from day to month
slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='title', unique_with='pub_date__month')
```

But I get this error

> 'NvcChannel' object has no attribute 'nvc__mac_address'

is it possible to do what i am trying to do? If so, where did i go wrong?

I looked at this question [override save to execute code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2307943/django-overriding-the-model-create-method)
and came up with this

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.pk:
        self.slug = AutoSlugField(max_length=50, unique=True, populate_from=('channel_index',self.nvc.mac_address))
    super(NvcChannel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nvc__mac_address` is only for database lookups (usually with `filter()`). You are trying to access a field of retrieved object, so you should use `nvcchannel.nvc.mac_address`

Comment: so can I do a db look up of the foreign key inside the model definition?