# How to avoid model edit in presave Django

Tags: python, django-models, python-3.5

I am trying to save in Django model at once this would trigger an event. When updating this model triggering the **start_event** again and again. How to trigger the event only at first time save not in update?

```
Image(models.Model):
    file_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    file_path = models.CharFiedld(max_length=500)
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        start_event(self.file_path)
        super(Image, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Using this model first create and update. **Create**

```
from models import Image
image = Image()
image.file_path = "path/to/file"
image.save()
```

After the event completion will use **Update**

```
from models import Image
image = Image.objects.get(file_path='path/to/file')
image.file_name = "file/name"
image.save()
```

How to trigger the event(start_event) only at first time save not in update?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2307943/django-overriding-the-model-create-method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Zev your info helped it! From the link [Django - Overriding the Model.create() method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2307943/django-overriding-the-model-create-method) found the solution.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.pk: # Checking if the oject has no pk
        start_event(self.file_path)
    super(Image, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```