# Whats the recommended way to update every instance of a source model when a new target instance is created in a manytomany model?

Tags: python, django, manytomanyfield

I have a website where I want to display a basic html table like so:

```
Product_Name | Attribute_1 | Attribute_2
----------------------------------------- 
Soap         | True        | True 
Shampoo      | False       | True
```

So I have created the classes `Product` and `Attribute` with a ManyToMany relationship.

**Models.py**

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    attributes = models.ManyToManyField(on_delete='CASCADE')

class Attribute(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1, default='N')
```

So I have two Attribute instances - Attribute_1 and Attribute_2.

When I create a new attribute (Attribute_3), is there a way I can update the relationships of all of my Product instances with a link to the new Attribute?

I know that Django creates a through table for m2m relationships. According to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/relations/), I know I can do something like:

`for prod_obj in Product.objects.all():
    prod_obj.add(new_attribute_object)`

But how do I ensure this happens automatically/consistently every time I create an attribute object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write a custom `save` method for your `Attribute` model that a) checks to see whether the `Attribute` object is being created for the first time; and b) if so, adds that `Attribute` to each `Product` in your database. For more information on writing a custom `save` method, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2307943/django-overriding-the-model-create-method).