# How to create a django model for JSONField that takes values from other fields from the same table?

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am writing a model in django which looks like this:

```
name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
info = JSONField()
```

Question:
For POST request, I will provide name and address as json. Now how should I store name and address in their respective fields and store json data i.e. "name:{...},address:{...}" and store it into info field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more or less how I create my post requests:

```
class MyPostView(View):
    def post(self, request):
        # Get request data
        data = json.loads(request.body)

        # Extract the values I  need
        name = data.get('name')
        address = data.get('address')

        # If the info already comes from the request do this
        info = data.get('info')

        # If you want to create the info field here do this
        info = {'name':name, 'address': address}

        # Create new model object
        new_profile = Profile()

        # Assign values
        new_profile.name = name
        new_profile.address = address
        new_profile.info = info

        # Save my object to database
        new_profile.save()

        # Return response (change this to whatever you want to return)
        return HttpResponse("Success")
```

Here I use class-based views but you can use function-based views the same way.
I'm just not sure why you want to save the information for name and address twice.

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can override the save method, which will add those fields to your info JSONField before saving the instance.

See: [Django - Overriding the Model.create() method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2307943/django-overriding-the-model-create-method)

Anyway I suggest you not doing so, because you are creating redundancy into columns of the very same table.